# How we can join with where condition result through laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have situation in laravel 5.1 with eloquent. That is very hard for me at this time to get the solution.

I have 7 tables in database which are not related to each other, but I want to get results with joining them all and with where clause.

My Tables relations are:

```
lifegroups -> Campuses -> locations -> address
```

and

```
lifegroups ->  grouptype -> groupuser -> user  // this is confusing little bit
```

and

```
lifegroups -> schedule -> recurrance
```

Notice the `lifegroup` table is associated with multiple other tables.

My Existing Query is:

```
$campusGroups = DB::table('campuses')
->Join('lifegroups','campuses.f1_id', '=', 'lifegroups.campusId')
->Join('locations', 'locations.group_id', '=', 'lifegroups.f1Id')
->Join('addresses', 'addresses.location_id', '=', 'locations.id')           
->Join('groups_users', 'groups_users.groupId', '=', 'lifegroups.id')
->Join('users', 'groups_users.userId', '=', 'users.id')
->distinct() //'users.first_name', 'users.last_name',
->select('lifegroups.*', 'campuses.name AS campusname', 'addresses.address', 'addresses.address2', 'addresses.city', 'addresses.province');

$groupLeaders = DB::table('campuses')
->Join('lifegroups', 'campuses.f1_id', '=', 'lifegroups.campusId')
->Join('groups_users', 'groups_users.groupId', '=', 'lifegroups.id')
->Join('users', 'groups_users.userId', '=', 'users.id')         
->distinct()
->select('lifegroups.id', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name');

$groupRecurrences = DB::table('campuses')
->Join('lifegroups', 'campuses.f1_id', '=', 'lifegroups.campusId')
->Join('schedules', 'schedules.event_id', '=', 'lifegroups.eventid')
->Join('recurrences', 'recurrences.schedule_id', '=', 'schedules.id')           
->distinct()
->select('recurrences.occurOnFriday', 'recurrences.occurOnSaturday', 'recurrences.occurOnMonday', 'recurrences.occurOnSunday', 'recurrences.occurOnThursday', 'recurrences.occurOnTuesday', 'recurrences.occurOnWednesday', 'recurrences.recurrenceFrequency', 'recurrences.recurrenceFrequencyMonthly', 'recurrences.recurrenceFrequencyWeekly', 'schedules.start_date', 'schedules.recurrence', 'lifegroups.id AS groupId');

if (Session::has('campus')){
    $campusId = Session::get('campus');
    $searchObj = $campusGroups->where('campuses.id', intval($campusId));
    $groupLeaders = $groupLeaders->where('campuses.id', intval($campusId));
    $groupRecurrences = $groupRecurrences->where('campuses.id', intval($campusId));
    $searchArray['campusId'] = $campusId;
}

if (Session::has('gender')){
    $gender = Session::get('gender');
    $searchObj = $campusGroups->where('lifegroups.gender', $gender);
    $groupLeaders = $groupLeaders->where('lifegroups.gender', $gender);
    $groupRecurrences = $groupRecurrences->where('lifegroups.gender', $gender);
    $searchArray['gender'] = $gender;
} else {
    $searchArray['gender'] = 'N/A';
}

if (Session::has('marital_status')){
    $marital_status = Session::get('marital_status');
    $searchObj = $campusGroups->where('lifegroups.marital_status', $marital_status);
    $groupLeaders = $groupLeaders->where('lifegroups.marital_status', $marital_status);
    $groupRecurrences = $groupRecurrences->where('lifegroups.marital_status', $marital_status);
    $searchArray['marital_status'] = $marital_status;
} else {
    $searchArray['marital_status'] = 'N/A';
}

if (Session::has('age')){ 
    $age = Session::get('age');
    $searchObj = $campusGroups->where('lifegroups.startAgeRange', $age);
    $groupLeaders = $groupLeaders->where('lifegroups.startAgeRange', $age);
    $groupRecurrences = $groupRecurrences->where('lifegroups.startAgeRange', $age);
    $searchArray['age'] = $age;
} else {
    $searchArray['age'] = 'N/A';
}   

if (Session::has('keyword')){
    $keyword = Session::get('keyword');
    $searchObj = $campusGroups->where('lifegroups.name', 'Like', '%'. $keyword . '%');
    //->orWhere('lifegroups.description', 'Like', '%'.$keyword.'%')
    //->orWhere('users.first_name', 'Like', '%'.$keyword.'%');
    $groupLeaders = $groupLeaders->where('lifegroups.name', 'Like', '%'. $keyword . '%');
    $groupRecurrences = $groupRecurrences->where('lifegroups.name', 'Like', '%'. $keyword . '%');
    $searchArray['keyword'] = $keyword;
} else {
    $searchArray['keyword'] = 'N/A';
}

$campusGroupsTemp = $campusGroups->get();
$campusGroups = []; 
$recurrenceGroups = [];
$groupLeaders = $groupLeaders->get();
$groupRecurrences = $groupRecurrences->get();
```

So this is a very long process and I can't add further search filters. Do you guys have any better idea how to do it with Laravel Eloquent, like

```
Lifegroups::with(['campuses', 'locations', 'addresses', 'grouptype', 'groupuser', 'users', 'schedules', 'recurrences'])
->where(['lifegroups.name', '=' 'name_value'],['lifegroups.description','like', '%like_valie%'], ['user.first_name', 'like', 'first_name_value'])
->get()->toArray();
```

If you are confused like me then only let me know how to do below mentioned thing with above type of tables scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This becomes very easy with Eloquent assuming you have your models setup correctly.  Just use dot notation to handle the nesting.

```
$data = Lifegroups::with([
    'campuses.locations.address',
    ['grouptype.groupuser.user', function($q) use ($first_name) {
        // Handle the constraints on the users table here.
        $q->where('name', 'like', $first_name)
    }],
    'schedule.recurrance'
])
    // Handle any constraints on the Lifegroups table here
    ->where('name', '=', 'name_value')
    ->where('description','like', '%like_valie%')
    ->get();
```

If you need to add more constraints for different tables, just add another parameter to the array we passed into the `with` function going as deep as you need to with the nexting and passing in a function with it where you will set the constraints like I did the users table.

Comment: Eloquent assuming you have your models setup correctly [Can you explain in detail]

Comment: You have models for your tables and they have the required relationship functions so they can be related to one another.

Comment: Are you serious, these are 8 tables with dozens of columns i even don't know how they relate, :( . because this project was managing someone else so don't know too much about it, anyway i need to know the relations then and i need to built the relations in models. hmm. let go for broke. anythanks for this solution, can you let me know one more thing only, can i change the array data column name and how can i check where condition for columns without any table.column ambigous issue.

Comment: this is not working giving error that explode accept string array given

Comment: ['grouptype.groupuser.user', function($q) use ($first_name) {
        // Handle the constraints on the users table here.
        $q->where('name', 'like', $first_name)
    }]

This is giving me error that explode accepts string array given. what to do ?

Comment: With your answer i have complete my 50% work thanks to you, except i can't make eager constraint where condition search it give me error. here is my code 

$searchArray['keyword']= 'debbie';

  $data = Groups::with(['campus','locations.address','grouptypes',
         'events.schedules.recurrences',['groupusers.users' => function($q)use($searchArray){
    $q->where('first_name','like','%debbie%');
   }]
  ])->Where('name','like','%fly%')->orWhere('description','like','%fly%')->distinct()->get()->toArray();